# Firebase get single item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

### Im trying to create a page that displays a single items data from a firebase database on a single page.

---

In my **app.router.ts** I have:

```
{ path: 'song/:key', component: SongDetailsComponent }
```

---

In my **song-details.component.ts** I have:

```
song:any;

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    let id = params['key'];
    this.song = this._firebaseService.getSong(id);
  });
}
```

In my **song-details.componenet.html** I have:

```
{{ song | json }}
```

---

And in my **firebase.service.ts** I have

```
  songsDatabaseRef: any;

  constructor(private _angularFire: AngularFire) {
    this.songsDatabaseRef = _angularFire.database.list('songs');
  }

  getSong(key: string) {
    return this._angularFire.database.list('songs/'+key);
  }
```

---

But when I go to the specified route for a song's detail I get an **error**:

```
error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: Error in ./SongDetailsComponent class SongDetailsComponent -
inline template:0:0 caused by: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

---

Once I added the async pipe I got the data to display but I can't access the properties of the json object.

---

This is the **json object**:

```
{ "artist": "Two Friends Big Bootie Mixes", "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/286347553/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89", "dateCreated": "9/10/2016", "download": "http://smarturl.it/BB10Download", "genres": { "bass": 0, "dubstep": 30, "future": 0, "hipHop": 0, "house": 50, "indie": 0, "pop": 0, "techno": 20 }, "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000186905340-xin8sf-t500x500.jpg", "title": "2F Big Bootie Mix, Volume 10 - Two Friends", "url": "http://soundcloud.com/twofriendsmixes5/bb10", "$key": "-KTgBcZudwBfhKcm68aa" }
```

---

When I try to get any property it says it is **undefined**. For example:

```
song title: {{(song | async | json)?.title}}
```

This returns null!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this._angularFire.database.list('songs/'+key)` is an Observable (FirebaseListObservable). You need to subscribe to it to get the data.

You can use:

```
{{ song | async | json }}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem though. Ill update the question

Comment: @MattThomas If you think about it when you write `{{(song | async | json)?.title}}` you're asking for `title` of the json, not the song... try `{{ (song |async)?.title }}` and if you really want to display it as json `{{ (song |async)?.title |json }}`.